# Batch file to call URL and find variables inside the response

Tags: command-line, batch, url

This is probably way beyond what a batch file can do, but I am trying to accomplish this:

Call a URL `http://127.0.0.1:7001/ec2/getCamerasEx?extraFormatting` which would require a username and password prompt to be filled out (I'm fine doing that manually).

The response will look similar to this repeating for each instance but with additional info.  I need to locate a specific string after "id" and then find the associated "physicalId" for it.  I'm in quite a bit over my head on this, and I doubt it is even something I can accomplish with a batch file, but I figured I'd ask just in case.:

```
 "audioEnabled":false,
        "backupType":"CameraBackupDefault",
        "controlEnabled":true,
        "dewarpingParams":"{\"enabled\":false,\"fovRot\":0,\"hStretch\":1,\"radius\":0.5,\"viewMode\":\"1\",\"xCenter\":0.5,\"yCenter\":0.5}",
        "disableDualStreaming":false,
        "failoverPriority":"Medium",
        "groupId":"",
        "groupName":"",
        "id":"{081c5328-ebc9-c717-2fad-6c219d4b265f}",
        "licenseUsed":true,
        "logicalId":"",
        "mac":"00-0D-F1-2B-3A-E0",
        "manuallyAdded":false,
        "maxArchiveDays":-30,
        "minArchiveDays":-1,
        "model":"DWC-MF21M4TIR",
        "motionMask":"5,0,0,44,32",
        "motionType":"2",
        "name":"Store Bathrooms",
        "parentId":"{9336be48-010a-dfb4-1925-5a695352eaf8}",
        "physicalId":"urn_uuid_32623361-6530-6665-6261-000df12b3ae0",
        "preferredServerId":"{9336be48-010a-dfb4-1925-5a695352eaf8}",
        "recordAfterMotionSec":5,
        "recordBeforeMotionSec":5,
        "scheduleEnabled":true,
        "scheduleTasks":[
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this fits your needs:

```
@echo off

:: Fill this fields with your username and password:
set Username=
set Password=
:: 
for /f tokens^=^2^,^3^ delims^=^"^: %%a in ('curl -s -u %Username%:%Password% http://127.0.0.1:7001/ec2/getCamerasEx?extraFormatting') do (
                                                                                                                                           if /i "%%~a"=="id" set ID=%%~b
                                                                                                                                           if /i "%%~a"=="physicalId" set PhysicalID=%%~b
                                                                                                                                          )
echo  ID: %ID%
echo  PhysicalID: %PhysicalID%
echo.
pause
```

Comment: Wow, I did not think it was possible!  Yes, the hard part seems to be solved.  There is a repeating list of ID and corresponding PhysicalID like above, so I need to search through all of the IDs in the response from the URL and find the 1 (actually 2) that match the ones I need to search for (from user input) and then return the 2 corresponding PhysicalIDs.  I THINK I can make a bunch of for and/or if statements for that, unless there is an easier way?

Comment: This can probably be easiely done with a for, where are these ID and PhysicallDs that you want to compare stored?

Comment: I would input the 1st and 2nd ID to search for and would need to return the 1st and 2nd physicalID that corresponds to them...

The URL returns a long list of every device connected to it, so that list in my original post is repeating for each device.  The list is always in the same order, so if I find the ID first and then find the next PhysicalID, it would correspond...

Comment: Wow!  OK, I need to sift through all this.  My main goal was to input 2 IDs and find the physical IDs of those cams (and then do some other stuff with them, which I've already worked out).  It looks like your Obs 2 will do that and I'll just need to rework the code a bit, which shouldn't be too difficult.  Thank you so much, I dont think I would have ever been able to figure this out on my own.  I want to read through it all so I can understand whats actually happening...

Comment: I'm not getting anything from this..  It doesnt appear to be processing properly, as if I remote the @echo off, I can see that there are no IDs being filled - everything is blank...

Comment: Do you have to input a different URL for each camera or just one and all gets listed?

Comment: I'm noticing that the OP has commented here on things pertinent to my answer. Is that really it @JosephSantangelo?

Comment: @ItWasntMe: I noticed the same thing...

Comment: The one URL will provide the full list of cams and params.  I modified it a bit and it appears the problem is in the initial loading of the response from curl/loading a temporary file (I saw in one of your obs that you referenced a file instead of the curl call, so I used that and saved the response directly to that file.  It still wasnt able to match any IDs...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, your goal is to separate id, physical id, for each item in your list, in an orderly way, first the ID, then the physical ID, for each camera that returns from its output in the curl command..

```bat
@echo off

set "_tab=       "
set "_login=YourUserNameHere:YourPasswordHere"
set "_cURL_cmd=curl -s -u %_login% http://127.0.0.1:7001/ec2/getCamerasEx?extraFormatting"

for /f tokens^=2-3delims^={}^,:^" %%i in ('%_cURL_cmd%^|findstr /l " id\"\:\"{ physicalId\":\""
   ')do if /i "%%~i" == "id" (echo\%_tab% %%i: %%j)else echo\%%i: %%j
```

**1.** Use `for /f` loop with multiple delimiters `{},:"`, taking advantage that they will be removed from the output, so they will be used partly for removing the output and partly as a delimiter

**2.** Use `findstr` to separate the `ID` and `physicalId`, where only the lines that contain the `ID` and `physicalId` will be listed, taking advantage of the fact that the output is already sorted, you have its output in the same order.

---

Returns:

```bat
        id: 081c5328-ebc9-c717-2fad-6c219d4b265f
physicalId: urn_uuid_32623361-6530-6665-6261-000df12b3ae0
        id: 106562ad-06c6-ea42-7413-1e9b852812bc
physicalId: urn_uuid_333236313332-3636-2d33-3636-312d3330
        id: 15e490d5-2b97-3bea-eba2-ad45a20a3c25
physicalId: urn_uuid_32616166-3836-6665-6130-000df12aaf86
        id: 18e6bc2a-d7f2-d030-6cf0-1fd668124452
physicalId: urn_uuid_32623035-6332-6666-3064-000df12b05c2
        id: 1d884232-c33c-922d-61c5-d0f568d0ffc7
physicalId: urn_uuid_32623036-3237-6666-6137-000df12b0627
        id: 1e3b120b-0894-6631-b831-513a8dfc9bbe
physicalId: urn_uuid_32623361-3664-6666-3264-000df12b3a6d
        id: 2b798b32-86f3-3c45-4a1c-daab08f5b138
physicalId: urn_uuid_32616166-3331-6665-6635-000df12aaf31
```

---

**Obs.1.:** If you don't need to output strings (`ID`  and `physicalID` ), then remove `2-` from `token^=2-3`, and  `%%j` from `echo\%%i %%j` command:

```bat
for /f tokens^=3delims^={}^,:^" %%i in ('%_cURL_cmd%^|findstr /l " id\":\"{ physicalId\":\""')do echo\%%i
```

Returns:

```bat
081c5328-ebc9-c717-2fad-6c219d4b265f
urn_uuid_32623361-6530-6665-6261-000df12b3ae0
106562ad-06c6-ea42-7413-1e9b852812bc
urn_uuid_333236313332-3636-2d33-3636-312d3330
15e490d5-2b97-3bea-eba2-ad45a20a3c25
urn_uuid_32616166-3836-6665-6130-000df12aaf86
18e6bc2a-d7f2-d030-6cf0-1fd668124452
urn_uuid_32623035-6332-6666-3064-000df12b05c2
1d884232-c33c-922d-61c5-d0f568d0ffc7
urn_uuid_32623036-3237-6666-6137-000df12b0627
1e3b120b-0894-6631-b831-513a8dfc9bbe
urn_uuid_32623361-3664-6666-3264-000df12b3a6d
2b798b32-86f3-3c45-4a1c-daab08f5b138
urn_uuid_32616166-3331-6665-6635-000df12aaf31
```

---

**Obs.:2.** From there, you can get more uses for your code, for example, find the `physicalID` of a particular camera `ID`:

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_login=YourUserNameHere:YourPasswordHere"
set "_ID=081c5328-ebc9-c717-2fad-6c219d4b265f"
set "_cURL_cmd=curl -s -u %_login% http://127.0.0.1:7001/ec2/getCamerasEx?extraFormatting"

for /f tokens^=3delims^={}^,:^" %%i in ('!_cURL_cmd!^|findstr /l " id\":\"{%_ID% physicalId\":\""'
   )do if not "!_CAM_loop!" == "%_ID%" (set "_CAM_loop=%%~i")else set "_physical_ID=%%~i" && goto %:^)

%:^)
echo\!_ID! & echo\!_physical_ID! & timeout -1 | endlocal
```

By adding the `ID` to `findstr`, you have each `ID` listed and just the desired `physicalID` after the given `ID`, so in each loop, set the `_CAM_loop` to the current `ID/%%j`, and in the next loop, if the `_CAM_ID` matches, (which was defined in the previous loop), then set your `physicalID` to the current looped `%%j` and exit the `for`.

---

**Obs.:3.** Also on the contrary, find the `ID` of a certain `physicalID` of the camera:

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_login=YourUserNameHere:YourPasswordHere"
set "_physicalId=urn_uuid_32623361-6530-6665-6261-000df12b3ae0"
set "_cURL_cmd=curl -s -u %_login% http://127.0.0.1:7001/ec2/getCamerasEx?extraFormatting"

for /f tokens^=3delims^={}^,:^" %%i in ('!_cURL_cmd!^|findstr /l " id\":\"{ physicalId\":\"%_physicalId%"'
    )do if not "%%~i" == "%_physicalId%" (set "_ID=%%~i")else goto %:^)

%:^)
echo\!_ID! & echo\!_physicalId! & timeout -1 | endlocal & goto :eOf
```

By adding the `physicalID` strings to `findstr`, all occurrences of the IDs will be listed, and one by one will be defined in `_ID`, and it will be available for comparisons in the next loop, then in the loop where it matches the `physicalID`, the id will already be setting, so, just exit loop without setting `ID` to current string in `%%j`.

---

**Obs.: 4.** To get multiple `physicalID's` of your cameras by providing multiple `IDs`, simply adapt using additional `for` loop by calling a function/lable using counters and incrementing as variable when defining them.

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_login=YourUserNameHere:YourPasswordHere"
set "_cURL_cmd=curl -s -u !_login! http://127.0.0.1:7001/ec2/getCamerasEx?extraFormatting"
set "_Multiples_IDs=cbea4225-934b-2344-ed37-13aa31295d58,081c5328-ebc9-c717-2fad-6c219d4b265f"

2>nul set /a "_cnt-=!_cnt!" & for /l %%L in (1 1 999)do set "_physical_ID_%%~L=" && set "_ID_%%~L="
for %%i in (%_Multiples_IDs%)do set /a "_cnt+=1+0" && call %:^] !_cnt! "%%~i" "!_cURL_cmd!" && call set "_ID_!_cnt!=%%~i"

%:^]
if not "%~1%~2" == "" for /f tokens^=3delims^={}^,:^" %%i in ('%~3^|findstr /l " id\":\"{%~2 physicalId\":\""'
   )do if not "!_CAM_loop!" == "%~2" (set "_CAM_loop=%%~i")else set "_physical_ID_%~1=%%~i" && exit /b

%:^)
for /l %%L in (1 1 999)do if not "!_physical_ID_%%~L!" == "" (
     echo\Variable name:          _ID_%%~L == !_ID_%%~L!
     echo\variable name: _physical_ID_%%~L == !_physical_ID_%%~L!
    )     

timeout -1 | endlocal & goto :eOf
```

To get in multiplication, and defining a variable (incrementable) for the occurrences, just define the multiple IDs in the same variable, and adapt it to the use of counters and functions, where the counters will be used to store the strings one by one in the same order with what the outputs are.

---

**Obs.: 5.** On the contrary, getting various `ID's` from your cameras, providing several `PhysicalID's`, just adapt using additional `for` loop calling a function/label using counters and incrementing as a variable when defining them, something like that, the junction of Obs.3 with Obs.: 4
d:)

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_login=YourUserNameHere:YourPasswordHere"
set "_cURL_cmd=curl -s -u !_login! http://127.0.0.1:7001/ec2/getCamerasEx?extraFormatting"
set "_Multiples_physicalIDs=urn_uuid_32623361-6530-6665-6261-000df12b3ae0,00-1C-A6-02-97-1D"

2>nul set /a "_cnt-=!_cnt!" & for /l %%L in (1 1 999)do set "_physical_ID_%%~L=" && set "_ID_%%~L="
for %%i in (%_Multiples_physicalIDs%)do set /a "_cnt+=1+0" && call %:^] !_cnt! "%%~i" "!_cURL_cmd!" && call set "_physical_ID_!_cnt!=%%~i"

%:^]
if not "%~1%~2" == "" for /f tokens^=3delims^={}^,:^" %%i in ('%~3 ^|findstr /l " id\":\"{ physicalId\":\"%~2"'
   )do if not "%%~i" == "%~2" (set "_ID_%~1=%%~i") else exit /b

%:^)
for /l %%L in (1 1 999)do if not "!_physical_ID_%%~L!" == "" (
    echo\Variable name:          _ID_%%~L == !_ID_%%~L!
    echo\variable name: _physical_ID_%%~L == !_physical_ID_%%~L!
   )      

timeout -1 | endlocal & goto :eOf
```

---

**Obs.: 6.** To get multiple fysicalIDs using user input in bat / cmd, I can suggest you this adaptation of your adaptation of my adaptation of your answer that noted my answer to your question in an adaptation of observation item 4., which in turn considers your comment noted in another answer OP, to the remark of item 2 of my answer to your question, or something similarly confusing so my limited english does not allow me to develop into clearer idea d;)

```bat
@echo off
                    
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_curl_login=username:password"
for %%i in (Old,New)do set /p "_%%~i_Cam_ID=Enter %%~i Cam ID: "
set "_cURL_cmd=curl -s -u !_curl_login! http://127.0.0.1:7001/ec2/getCamerasEx?extraFormatting"

for %%i in (Old,New)do call %:^] "%%~i" !_%%~i_Cam_ID! "!_cURL_cmd!"

%:^]
if not "%~1%~2" == "" for /f tokens^=3delims^={}^,:^" %%i in ('%~3 ^|findstr /l " id\":\"{%~2 physicalId\":\""'
   )do if not "!_CAM_loop!" == "%~2" (set "_CAM_loop=%%~i") else set "_%~1_physical_ID=%%~i" && exit /b

%:^)
for %%i in (Old,New)do echo\Variable name:      _%%~i_Cam_ID == !_%%~i_Cam_ID! && (
    echo\variable name: _%%i_physical_ID == !_%%i_physical_ID!
   )      

echo\ & timeout -1 | <con: echo\Press Any Key To Exit or F13 To Continue d;) & endlocal & goto :eOf
```

String line input and output:

```bat
Tested line 5101:  d8e6a403-ccb7-4ded-cd9f-b67aa7e397e3
Tested line 5113:  00-1C-A6-02-97-1D
Tested line 4909:  cbea4225-934b-2344-ed37-13aa31295d58
Tested line 4921:  urn_uuid_32633161-6331-6665-6638-000df12c1ac1
```

Outputs:

```bat
Enter Old Cam ID: d8e6a403-ccb7-4ded-cd9f-b67aa7e397e3
Enter New Cam ID: cbea4225-934b-2344-ed37-13aa31295d58
Variable name:      _Old_Cam_ID == d8e6a403-ccb7-4ded-cd9f-b67aa7e397e3
variable name: _Old_physical_ID == 00-1C-A6-02-97-1D
Variable name:      _New_Cam_ID == cbea4225-934b-2344-ed37-13aa31295d58
variable name: _New_physical_ID == urn_uuid_32633161-6331-6665-6638-000df12c1ac1

Press Any Key To Exit or F13 To Continue d;)
```

---

**Obs.: 7.** You can also use more searches for physical IDs using `For /L` (*Conditionally perform a command for a range of numbers*):

```bat
 @echo off
                    
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_curl_login=username:password"
for /l %%L in (0 1 9)do set "_Cam_ID_#%%~L=" & set "_physical_ID_#%%~L="
for /l %%L in (0 1 9)do set /p "_Cam_ID_#%%~L=  Enter Camera ID #%%~L: "
set "_cURL_cmd=curl -s -u !_curl_login! http://127.0.0.1:7001/ec2/getCamerasEx?extraFormatting"

for /l %%L in (0 1 9)do call %:^] "#%%~L" !_Cam_ID_#%%~L! "!_cURL_cmd!"

%:^]
if not "%~1%~2" == "" for /f tokens^=3delims^={}^,:^" %%i in ('%~3 ^|findstr /l " id\":\"{%~2 physicalId\":\""'
   )do if not "!_CAM_loop!" == "%~2" (set "_CAM_loop=%%~i")else set "_physical_ID_%~1=%%~i" && exit /b

%:^)
for /l %%L in (0 1 9)do  echo\Variable name:       _Cam_ID_#%%~L == !_Cam_ID_#%%~L! && (
    echo\variable name:  _physical_ID_#%%~L == !_physical_ID_#%%~L!
   )

echo\ & timeout -1 | <con: echo\Press Any Key To Exit or F13 To Continue d;) & endlocal & goto :eOf
```

---

Returns:

```bat
Enter Cam ID #0: 1e3b120b-0894-6631-b831-513a8dfc9bbe
Enter Cam ID #1: 2f1c08ba-d44e-c96c-c9b9-d0172c8a44c8
Enter Cam ID #2: 638b66d6-683a-4fb3-31ea-90d8d0e44d10
Enter Cam ID #3: 760ed327-d2fe-802d-7574-83c37e3292ba
Enter Cam ID #4: 80da2ce7-ef02-1c38-7395-a786bac1b236
Enter Cam ID #5: aa3acc69-12b7-6045-f9b7-eaa7b54fc3f8
Enter Cam ID #6: cbea4225-934b-2344-ed37-13aa31295d58
Enter Cam ID #7: e5a72a3f-9bf1-6e6d-22ca-7084b91a228f
Enter Cam ID #8: e8290e6a-343e-2e14-8f37-0343aebbd797
Enter Cam ID #9: e8bc0e2c-97cb-94f4-493b-37f79122184e
Variable name:       _Cam_ID_#0 == 1e3b120b-0894-6631-b831-513a8dfc9bbe
variable name:  _physical_ID_#0 == urn_uuid_32623361-3664-6666-3264-000df12b3a6d
Variable name:       _Cam_ID_#1 == 2f1c08ba-d44e-c96c-c9b9-d0172c8a44c8
variable name:  _physical_ID_#1 == urn_uuid_32616166-3933-6665-3933-000df12aaf93
Variable name:       _Cam_ID_#2 == 638b66d6-683a-4fb3-31ea-90d8d0e44d10
variable name:  _physical_ID_#2 == urn_uuid_32616137-6233-6665-3762-000df12aa7b3
Variable name:       _Cam_ID_#3 == 760ed327-d2fe-802d-7574-83c37e3292ba
variable name:  _physical_ID_#3 == urn_uuid_32306138-3735-6665-6332-000df120a875
Variable name:       _Cam_ID_#4 == 80da2ce7-ef02-1c38-7395-a786bac1b236
variable name:  _physical_ID_#4 == urn_uuid_32616165-6439-6665-3465-000df12aaed9
Variable name:       _Cam_ID_#5 == aa3acc69-12b7-6045-f9b7-eaa7b54fc3f8
variable name:  _physical_ID_#5 == urn_uuid_32303837-3834-6665-6434-000df1208784
Variable name:       _Cam_ID_#6 == cbea4225-934b-2344-ed37-13aa31295d58
variable name:  _physical_ID_#6 == urn_uuid_32633161-6331-6665-6638-000df12c1ac1
Variable name:       _Cam_ID_#7 == e5a72a3f-9bf1-6e6d-22ca-7084b91a228f
variable name:  _physical_ID_#7 == 00-1C-A6-02-9A-EF
Variable name:       _Cam_ID_#8 == e8290e6a-343e-2e14-8f37-0343aebbd797
variable name:  _physical_ID_#8 == urn_uuid_32306137-3966-6665-3939-000df120a79f
Variable name:       _Cam_ID_#9 == e8bc0e2c-97cb-94f4-493b-37f79122184e
variable name:  _physical_ID_#9 == urn_uuid_333236313331-3633-2d33-3733-392d3330

Press Any Key To Exit or F13 To Continue d;)
```

---

## Some further reading:

- **[`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**
- **[`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**
- **[`Findstr /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**
- **[Redirection |, <, > 2>, ...](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**
- **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**
- **[Escape Characters with Findstr Command](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr-escapes.html)**
- **[Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes in Command Line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)**

**[How does the Windows Command Interpreter cmd.exe Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)**

**[How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)**

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue where I have a ! in the password and the script appears to be functioning properly now!  I have to make some more edits to fully fit my needs, but it is now returning the correct PhysicalID for the CamID!

Answer (score 0):

Combining everything I've been working on, this is testing and working.  Wanted to say thank you for the help with this, I would have never figured it out on my own.  I was able to dissect most of the code and make sense of it, although there are still some things that are baffling me...

```
@echo off
REM Last Edited 01/15/22 03:28PM

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_curl_login=username:Password"
for %%i in (Old,New)do set /p "_%%~i_Cam_ID=Enter %%~i Cam ID: "
set "_cURL_cmd=curl -s -u !_curl_login! http://127.0.0.1:7001/ec2/getCamerasEx?extraFormatting"
set "_cURL_rebuild_cmd=curl -s -u !_curl_login! http://127.0.0.1:7001/api/rebuildArchive?action=start&mainPool=1"
for %%i in (Old,New)do call %:^] "%%~i" !_%%~i_Cam_ID! "!_cURL_cmd!"

%:^]
if not "%~1%~2" == "" for /f tokens^=3delims^={}^,:^" %%i in ('!_cURL_cmd!^|findstr /l " id\":\"{%~2 physicalId\":\""'
   )do if not "!_CAM_loop!" == "%~2" (set "_CAM_loop=%%~i") else set "_%~1_physical_ID=%%~i" && exit /b

%:^)
for %%i in (Old,New)do echo Cam ID !_%%~i_Cam_ID! matches Physical ID !_%%i_physical_ID!

for /F "skip=1" %%F in ('wmic LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType^=3 GET DeviceID ^| findstr [A-Z]') do (
    echo Checking Drive %%F%...
    set oldDirectory=%%F%\DW Spectrum Media\low_quality\!_1_physical_ID!
    set newDirectory=%%F%\DW Spectrum Media\low_quality\!_2_physical_ID!
    if exist "!oldDirectory!" (
        echo Processing Drive %%F% ...  
        if exist "!oldDirectory!\info.txt" del /q "!oldDirectory!\info.txt" > null
        if exist "!newDirectory!\info.txt" move "!newDirectory!\info.txt" "!oldDirectory!" > null
        if exist "!newDirectory!" rmdir /S /Q "!newDirectory!" > null
        if exist "!oldDirectory!" rename "!oldDirectory!" !_2_physical_ID! > null
    )
    set oldDirectory=%%F%\DW Spectrum Media\hi_quality\!_1_physical_ID!
    set newDirectory=%%F%\DW Spectrum Media\hi_quality\!_2_physical_ID!
    if exist "!oldDirectory!" (
        if exist "!oldDirectory!\info.txt" del /q "!oldDirectory!\info.txt" > null
        if exist "!newDirectory!\info.txt" move "!newDirectory!\info.txt" "!oldDirectory!" > null
        if exist "!newDirectory!" rmdir /S /Q "!newDirectory!" > null
        if exist "!oldDirectory!" rename "!oldDirectory!" !_2_physical_ID! > null
    )
)

set /p Rebuild=Done, Rebuild Archive? ([Y]/N)
if /i not "%Rebuild%" == "N" (
    echo Initiating Archive Rebuild...
    !_cURL_rebuild_cmd! >null
) else (
    echo Skipping Archive Rebuild...
)
echo\ & timeout -1 | <con: echo\Press Any Key To Exit
if exist null del null
endlocal
exit
```